# Unable to uninstall with custom WiX installer

Tags: wpf, wix, windows-installer, uninstallation

I've created a custom WiX Burn installer using `ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost` with a `WPF` frontend (using WiX 3.9).

The installation of my MSI works correctly.    I use `mBootstrapperApplication.Engine.Detect();` to determine if the MSI package is present or not.  If it is, I follow a flow similar to that of the installation, in order to uninstall:

`mBootstrapperApplication.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Uninstall);`

Once it's in the `PlanComplete` event and the `Status == 0`, I call `mBootstrapperApplication.Engine.Apply(System.IntPtr.Zero);` and will eventually get back to the `ApplyComplete` event with `Status == 0`.

Unfortunately though, nothing seems to have happened at that point.

I'm hooked up to the `ExecuteMsiMessage` and it has no messages coming through.  When `ExecuteBegin`is fired, `PackageCount` is 0, where I believe it should be 1.

I can post code if necessary.  My wxs file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
  <Bundle Name="CustomInstallBootstrapper" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Square Enix Ltd." UpgradeCode="33CA185D-083B-4D45-A0AE-693C2E09C5F0">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
        <Payload SourceFile="D:\Project\CustomInstallBootstrapper\BootstrapperCore.config"/>
        <Payload SourceFile="D:\Project\CustomInstallBootstrapper\CustomInstallBootstrapper.dll"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="ignore" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="ignore" />

    <Chain>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx451Redist"/>
        <MsiPackage Id="LauncherMSI" SourceFile="D:\Project\Launcher.msi" Cache="yes" Visible="no">
        </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

If I run the MSI on its own, I can install and uninstall it without any issues.

Comment: My guess would be that it doesn't detect the MSI as installed, would need the Burn log from %TEMP% to verify what's actually happening.

Comment: Forgot that it created those logs.  Looks like it has found dependents (earlier versions of my installer).  This is why I should have used a VM..., thanks @SeanHall